# config for Nlog in class library

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a class library called `Logging`. In the solution I have many projects: ASP.NET MVC app, WCF services, and other projects.  The problem in that I must put config file for every project. I want to the config file locate only in one place, in the class library. Is this possible?

I'm using NLog.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an existing item (NLog.config from your class library) to all others projects as a link. An you'll be able to manage NLog configuration in one place.

1) Right click to a project - Add -> Existing Item...

[image]

2) Navigate to your class library folder, select NLog.config file and add it as a link.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. But it will be work only if I change config file in VS, and make publsih, and deploy all projects.